# Partial Fractions (3 Factors)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

[This document](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0746834248847.di020749.02p0056u.pdf) outlines a shortcut for partial fractions involving 2 factors in the denominator (P(x) + a) and (P(x) + b).

At the end of the document it gives a challenge to find a similar shortcut for 3 factors (P(x) + a), (P(x) + b) and (P(x) + c). I have not been able to come up with anything. Was wondering if anyone else can figure this one out.

Comment: can you post your problem here please?

Comment: I would but it's layout intensive and I don't know LaTeX. If someone would be so kind as to do it for me...

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html

Comment: I've made an edit to further describe the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly the same philosophy as for two factors; for simplicity, I shall note $p$ instead of $p(x)$.

Write $$\frac{1}{(p+a)(p+b)(p+c)}=\frac{A}{p+a}+\frac{B}{p+b}+\frac{C}{p+c}$$ Reduce to same denominator. Then$$1=A(p+b)(p+c)+B(p+a)(p+c)+C(p+a)(p+b)$$ Now, make $p=-a$ and get $$1=A(b-a)(c-a)$$ Do the same with $p=-b$ and get $$1=B(a-b)(c-b)$$ and again for $p=-c$ to get $$1=C(a-c)(b-c)$$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

it is the term
$\frac{1}{(p(x)+a)(p(x)+b)(p(x)+c)}$
the solution is given by
${\frac {1}{ \left( -c+a \right)  \left( -c+b \right)  \left( p(x)+c
 \right) }}-{\frac {1}{ \left( -b+a \right)  \left( -c+b \right) 
 \left( p(x)+b \right) }}+{\frac {1}{ \left( -c+a \right)  \left( -b+a
 \right)  \left( p(x)+a \right) }}$